# Returning USERS from asp.net Identity 2.0 with Iqueryable

Tags: entity-framework, angularjs, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-identity, inner-exception

```
  //GET api/Account/AllUsers
    [Route("AllUsers")]
    public List<IdentityUser> GetUsers()
    {
        var users = UserManager.Users.ToList();
        return users;
        //return query;
    }
```

[image: ERROR]

This is the returned error, nothing else is occurring when this Route is called. The only time the ApplicationUser is called is during the login process, which I then navigate to this view and call this route on the page load which errors out. Not sure if it's EntityFramework, code on the backend or ignorance.

```
    public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string BirthDate { get; set; }
    public bool IsDriver { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
}

public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser> 
{
    public ApplicationDbContext()
        : base("DmmContext", false)            
    {

    }

}
```

The above is the ApplicationUser class.

```
     //GET api/Account/AllUsers
    [Route("AllUsers")]
    public List<ApplicationUser> GetUsers()
    {
        var users = UserManager.Users.ToList();
        return users;
        //return query;
    }
```

Comment: Is this supposed to be an OData API?

Comment: I thought so. I'm still learning sorry for the ignorance. First attempt with WebApi and the newer technologies.

Answer (score 1):

Since your using ASP.NET Identity 2, Can you try this instead?

```
//GET api/Account/AllUsers
[Route("AllUsers")]
public async Task<List<ApplicationUser>> GetUsers()
{
    var users = await UserManager.Users.ToListAsync();
    return users;
}
```

Comment: I don't have ToListAsync() as an option, I tried ToList() which errors : 'await' operator can only be used within an async method. I then tried adding async to the method which ERRORS : 1. return type of an async method must be void, Task or Task<>, 2. Cannot await 'system.collections.generic.list<microsoft.aspnet.identity.entityframework.identityuser>.

Comment: Sorry forgot the async and task.. post is edited.  Perhaps you could try UserManager.Users.ToList() without await, async and task?

Comment: I tried the above and I'm getting Type conversion errors from IdentityUser to ApplicationUser. When I use the EDIT above  I return the IdentityUser values but not the extended properties within ApplicationUser (obviously). However, I need the other properties. Any idea? The ApplicationUser class is also in the original post, that's the information I'm looking to get along with the IdentityUser class info.

Answer (score 1):

you can return Iqueryable USERS list from web api by following way :

```
   [Route("AllUsers")]
   public IQueryable<User> GetUsers()
    {
       return db.users;
    }
```